# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED on ONSENUI VS2015

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui

i have an application Cordova Tools (Visual Studio) with OnsenUi framework. It's working fine, using the code below.

```
             <ons-icon icon="fa fa-globe" fixed-width="true" onclick="window.open('http://www.mywebsite.com.br', '_blank', 'location=yes')"></ons-icon>
```

But when i try to use my social profiles (Pinterest,instagram ..)  with : https://
I'm receiving this error:

```
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

webpage not available

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I've changed my code to :

```
            <ons-icon icon="fa fa-globe" fixed-width="true" onclick="window.open('https://www.myinstagram.com', '_blank')"></ons-icon>
```

Just  removing : 'location=yes'